# How to divide screen to two parts in react-native?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I'm new in react-native, and I'm trying to divide screen to tow part, the first part is the header or the navigation bar wish have a specific height about 40px the second part is the body or the content of the app wish his height must be the available height on the phone screen, I tried to use flex box method but it's not working!
That's my code:

```
<View style={styles.mainContainer}>
    <View style={styles.navBar}>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.body}>
    </View>
</View>
```

Style:

```
mainContainer: {
  height: '100%',
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
},
navBar: {
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
  justifyContent: 'space-between',
  alignItems: 'center',
  backgroundColor: '#f1f1f1',
  height: 30,
},
body: {
  flex: 3,
  display: 'flex',
},
```

Comment: Change `height: '100%'` to `height: '100vh'` ... or add rule `html, body { height: 100%; }`

Answer (score 5):

just use this way, i hope this will work.

```
 <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'}}>
   <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:"green"}}>
    <Text>hello world 1.........</Text>
    <Text>hello world 1.........</Text>
    <Text>hello world 1.........</Text>
    <Text>hello world 1.........</Text>
    </View>
      <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:"yellow"}}>
    <Text>hello world 2.........</Text>
    <Text>hello world 2.........</Text>
    <Text>hello world 2.........</Text>
    <Text>hello world 2.........</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine. See it running on Snack at: https://snack.expo.io/S1LHFmFyG

It's likely that you use an older version of React Native that doesn't support percentages. They [landed early this year](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/3f49e743bea730907066677c7cbfbb1260677d11) so you need RN [v0.42.3](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.42.3) or later in order to use them.

<sup>On a side note, there's a few unnecessary lines of code there in case you would like to make it more DRY. You don't need to declare `display` as it's `flex` by default, `flexDirection` is also set to `column` by default, and if you want a stripe of 40px your `height` should be `40` but I'm sure you're aware of that.</sup>

Comment: And how to check react-native version I don't find lot of resources? and thank you!

Comment: Run `react-native --version` in your project directory.